# Printing out all of enum values as type String in Java

Tags: java, enums, stream

I have an enum with enum values. I want to print the list of the enum values only.

Not just the enum. I have read about `Value Of` but see thats not the correct way to go at it.

This is what I want printed:

People Out

People In

Here is my enum with values in it. I added a constructor.

```
public enum People {
    OUT("People out"),
    IN("People in");

private final String name;

People(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  } 
}
```

The method to retrieve the enums is:

```
public String retrieveEnumValues() {
        return Stream.of(People.values()).
                map(People::name).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));

    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The `name()` method of an `enum` is a built-in method declared in the implicit super class `Enum`. It returns the enum constant name, e.g. `OUT`, and it is `final` so it cannot be overridden to return anything else. --- `People::name` is called a *method reference*, so why would you believe that it resolves to the value of your `name` *field*?

Comment: I'd recommend not calling a field in an enum `name` - too much scope for getting confused with the `name` method.  Can you call it something different?

Answer (score 0):

`People::name` refers to standard enum's method name(), you should provide getter for your `name` field and using it `People::getName`.